My WinUI 3 app sporadically crashes after clicking a button on a user control that executes code via commands from Dependency Properties
I have a winui 3 project where I use the MVVM pattern with the help of the MVVM toolkit from microsoft.
I created a UserControl that has 2 DependencyProperties of type ICommand. So that when I use this Control in my View then I can execute the code for the button clicks from the viewmodel to align with the mvvm principles.
UserControl:
 public sealed partial class MyDialog : UserControl
 {
     public static readonly DependencyProperty YesSelectedCommandProperty = 
         DependencyProperty.Register("YesSlectedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(AddinAutoAttachDialog), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnYesCommandChanged));

     public static readonly DependencyProperty NoSelectedCommandProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("NoSelectedCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(AddinAutoAttachDialog), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnNoCommandChanged));

     public ICommand YesSlectedCommand
     {
         get { return (ICommand)GetValue(YesSelectedCommandProperty); }
         set { SetValue(YesSelectedCommandProperty, value); }
     }

     public ICommand NoSlectedCommand
     {
         get { return (ICommand)GetValue(NoSelectedCommandProperty); }
         set { SetValue(NoSelectedCommandProperty, value); }
     }
     public MyDialog()
     {
         this.InitializeComponent();
     }

The correspoding xaml code:
  <Button Content="Yes"
          Command="{x:Bind YesSlectedCommand, Mode=OneTime}"/>

  <Button Content="No"
          Command="{x:Bind NoSlectedCommand, Mode=OneTime}" />

I use it in my view like this:
<Window ....>
    <components:MyDialog Visibility="{x:Bind MainViewModel.ShowMyDialog, Mode=OneWay}"
         YesSlectedCommand="{x:Bind MainViewModel.YesSelected, Mode=OneWay}"
         NoSlectedCommand="{x:Bind MainViewModel.NoSelected, Mode=OneWay}" />
    <InfoBar IsOpen="True"
         Severity="Success"
         Title="..." 
         Visibility="{x:Bind MainViewModel.ShowSuccessInfoBar, Mode=OneWay}"/>

    <InfoBar IsOpen="True"
         Severity="Error"
         Title="..."
         Visibility="{x:Bind MainViewModel.ShowErrorInfoBar, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Window>


Then in my view model I execute a similar code (mostly changing the visibility of UI elements):
internal partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool showMyDialog = false;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool showSuccessInfoBar = false;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool showErrorInfoBar = false;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void YesSelected()
    {
        bool succeeded = ExecuteSomeOperations();
        ShowMyDialog = false;
        ShowSuccessInfoBar = succeeded;
        ShowErrorInfoBar = !succeeded;
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void NoSelected()
    {
        ShowMyDialog = false;
        ShowErrorInfoBar = true;
    }
}

Weirdly enough my app crashes sometimes when I select the no button or sometimes for the yes button as well. But other times it displays everything correctly.
When i attached my debugger the only thing i saw was this line of message: The program '[9964] MyWindow.exe' has exited with code 3221226107 (0xc000027b).
I inspected the event viewer where I found this:
Faulting application name: MyWindow.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x661f0000
Faulting module name: Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll, version: 3.1.4.0, time stamp: 0x343afd70
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x00000000003b9584
Faulting process id: 0x0x4930
Faulting application start time: 0x0x1DAFE12C2C9EF06
Faulting module path: \...\Microsoft.ui.xaml.dll
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 

I tried wrapping it in a try catch block but no exceptions were caught and my code inside the commands that modify the UI elements visibility in the Yes/NoSelected methods could execute successfully. I also tried to look for binding failures because it seems to crash when i modify the UI. (btw I do not modify the UI from another thread) so I also tried this:
public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.DebugSettings.BindingFailed += (s, e) =>
    {
        File.AppendAllText(LogPath, $"BindingFailed: {e.Message}");
    };
}

But there were no logs regarding the binding failure in my log file.
What could be the issue here?

From a Windows standpoint, .NET exceptions in WinUI3 end up showing as nothing super useful in event viewer. You should debug the app and when you debug, you should get a more readable .NET exception

"YesSlectedCommand" and "NoSlectedCommand" are typos right?

Do you still have issues if the YesSlectedCommand and NoSlectedCommand in your view model are empty?

@SimonMourier The problem is that when I debug it and I click on one of the buttons the crashes. After that the debug output shown no exception in the log only this line at the end: The program '[9964] MyWindow.exe' has exited with code 3221226107 (0xc000027b)

@AndrewKeepCoding Yes it is only a typo. I just tried to remove the not relevant part of the code and made a typo.
When I tried to remove the body of the Yes/NoSlectedCommand methods then the issue does not occur. It seems when the the data-bound properties (ShowMyDialog, ShowErrorInfoBar) are updated then the app crashes sometimes. I shared more code in my question about this part in the view and viewmodel

Can you share code around your dialog?

The issue was with the data-bindings. I forgot to use a boolean to visibility converter for the visibility of my controls. But in my case the root element is a Window in my view where it is not possible to use x:bind with a converter so i had to switch to the Binding markup extension. As the data context is different for x:bind and Binding I had to use the data context from my container grid where it is set.
So I modified the code from this:
<InfoBar IsOpen="True"
         Severity="Success"
         Title="..." 
         Visibility="{x:Bind MainViewModel.ShowSuccessInfoBar, Mode=OneWay}"/>

to this:
<InfoBar IsOpen="True"
         Severity="Success"
         Title="..."
         Visibility="{Binding ElementName=myGrid, Path=DataContext.ShowSuccessInfoBar, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />


It solved the sporadic crashing issue but I still don't understand why did it work on the first place, because sometimes it worked without issues.

The built-in bool-to-visibility converter should work. I'm not sure if the missing converter is the issue here.

Well it did not work, because after I started to use mine instead, the issue was gone.
